# How to use decider in Spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm new to Spring batch. I've created a decider which returns a FlowExecutionStatus as "YES" / "NO". Based on the `FlowExecutionStatus`, I need to call `step2()` or `step3()`.

In my below code, `step2()` is getting called before decider. How to modify the code so that decider will be called and based on the `FlowExecutionStatus` returned bu the decider, either `step2()` or `step3()` should be called. Please help.

```
@Autowired
private NumberDecider decider;

@Bean
public Job NumberLoaderJob() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("numberLoaderJob").start(step1()).listener(new MyNumberJobListener())
            .next(decider).on("YES").to(step2())
            .from(decider).on("NO").to(step3()).end().build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").tasklet(new Tasklet() {

        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Exiting step1() execute()");
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    }).build();
}

/**
 * Step 2
 *
 * @return
 * @throws NumberFormatException
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Bean
public Step step2() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2").listener(new MyStepListener())
            .<OrderNumber, OrderNumber>chunk(Integer.valueOf(chunkSize)).faultTolerant()
            .listener(new MyChunkListener()).reader(new MyItemReader())
            .listener(new MyItemReaderListener()).writer(customItemWriter())
            .listener(new MyWriteListener()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need to to set the exit status in `step1` so that the decider picks it up and make the decision:

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {

   return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").tasklet(new Tasklet() {

       @Override
       public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
          System.out.println("Exiting step1() execute()");
          chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("YES")); // or NO
          return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
       }

    }).build();
}
```

EDIT: I thought that the decider should make the decision based on the exit status of step1, hence the previous sample. So adding a sample to show how to use a decider (after clarification):

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobExecutionDecider;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return steps.get("step1")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDecider decider() {
        return (jobExecution, stepExecution) -> new FlowExecutionStatus("YES"); // or NO
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return steps.get("step2")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("world");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step3() {
        return steps.get("step3")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("!!");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .next(decider())
                    .on("YES").to(step2())
                    .from(decider()).on("NO").to(step3())
                    .end()
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

In this example, step1 is executed first, then the decider. If the decider returns `YES`, step2 is executed and if returns `NO`, step3 is executed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mahmoud. I still see the same issue. Step 2 is executing first then step 1.           
      @Bean
 public Job numberLoaderJob() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("numberLoaderJob").start(step1()).listener(new NumberJobListener())
    .on("YES").to(step2()).on("NO").to(step3()).end().build();
 }

Comment: Could you please guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65194027/duplicate-step-step2-detected-in-execution-of-job-job-if-either-step-fails ?