# The bean 'step1', defined in class path resource [com/example/config/JobConfig.class], could not be registered

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jobexecutiondecider

I am looking to make the use of `JobExecutionDecider` in my Spring Batch App. I've taken reference: [How to use decider in Spring batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168976/how-to-use-decider-in-spring-batch).

For the code I written I am getting below error. Note: Surely I don't want to override the beans in my code. Any suggestion why this error?

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-01-01 19:32:30.859 ERROR 13800 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'step1', defined in class path resource [com/example/config/JobConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/example/JobConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

JobConfig.java

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public Tasklet step1Tasklet() {
        return new Step1Tasklet();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDecider decider() {
        return new MyJobExecutionDecider();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(step1Tasklet())
                .build();
    }
    
    // Here I used inbuild Tasklet
    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    log.debug("Step2Tasklet is executed...");
                    System.out.println("world");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step3() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    log.debug("Step3Tasklet is executed...");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .start(step1())
                .next(decider())
                    .on("YES").to(step2())
                    .from(decider()).on("NO").to(step3())
                    .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

MyJobExecutionDecider.java

```
public class MyJobExecutionDecider implements JobExecutionDecider{

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return new FlowExecutionStatus("YES");
    }
}
```

Step1Tasklet.java

```
@Slf4j
public class Step1Tasklet implements Tasklet{
    
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Step1Tasklet is executed...");
        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("YES")); // or NO
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

SpringBatchDeciderApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchDeciderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchDeciderApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the error, there are two beans named `step1`, one in `com/example/config/JobConfig` and another one in `com/example/JobConfiguration`. Make sure you have a single bean with that name in your application context or enable bean definition overriding as suggested by spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your example. Basically I copied your code and ran (except I remove a line in Tasklet). It is working fine. I have pushed the code at github at https://github.com/bigzidane/spring-batch-validate-reader

Please pull and try by yourself. Put comments in case you are having the same issue.

If decider is Yes, it was executing Step1 and Step2

```
2020-01-01 12:03:32.415  INFO 7300 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.d.SpringBatchDeciderApplication  : Starting SpringBatchDeciderApplication on WINDOWS-ESDA5FC with PID 7300 (C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-batch\target\classes started by dotha in C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-batch)
2020-01-01 12:03:32.419  INFO 7300 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.d.SpringBatchDeciderApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-01 12:03:33.650  INFO 7300 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-01-01 12:03:33.910  INFO 7300 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-01-01 12:03:34.045  INFO 7300 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2020-01-01 12:03:34.305  INFO 7300 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2020-01-01 12:03:34.493  INFO 7300 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.d.SpringBatchDeciderApplication  : Started SpringBatchDeciderApplication in 2.525 seconds (JVM running for 3.001)
2020-01-01 12:03:34.495  INFO 7300 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2020-01-01 12:03:34.617  INFO 7300 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2020-01-01 12:03:34.638  INFO 7300 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2020-01-01 12:03:34.652  INFO 7300 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
world
2020-01-01 12:03:34.660  INFO 7300 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2020-01-01 12:03:34.663  INFO 7300 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-01-01 12:03:34.664  INFO 7300 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

If decider is No, it was executing Step1 and Step3

```
2020-01-01 12:00:45.046  INFO 20384 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.d.SpringBatchDeciderApplication  : Starting SpringBatchDeciderApplication on WINDOWS-ESDA5FC with PID 20384 (C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-batch\target\classes started by dotha in C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-batch)
2020-01-01 12:00:45.049  INFO 20384 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.d.SpringBatchDeciderApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-01 12:00:46.176  INFO 20384 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-01-01 12:00:46.393  INFO 20384 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-01-01 12:00:46.499  INFO 20384 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2020-01-01 12:00:46.703  INFO 20384 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2020-01-01 12:00:46.862  INFO 20384 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.d.SpringBatchDeciderApplication  : Started SpringBatchDeciderApplication in 2.205 seconds (JVM running for 2.705)
2020-01-01 12:00:46.864  INFO 20384 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2020-01-01 12:00:46.954  INFO 20384 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2020-01-01 12:00:46.982  INFO 20384 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2020-01-01 12:00:47.006  INFO 20384 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step3]
2020-01-01 12:00:47.017  INFO 20384 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2020-01-01 12:00:47.030  INFO 20384 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-01-01 12:00:47.033  INFO 20384 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```